# How to do nonlinear substitution?

Tags: symbolic, expression-manipulation, coordinate-transformation

Suppose, I have an expression. For example:

$$\cos^5(\phi) \sin^3(\theta)$$

And I want to change variables to $(x, y, z)$, knowing that the new variables are related to $\theta$ and $\phi$, via given function, for example

$$x = \cos(\phi) \sin(\theta), y = \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta), z = \cos(\theta)$$.

Can I do it in *Mathematica* in an automatic way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is **not unique**.

```
coordinates = {x -> Cos[ϕ] Sin[θ], y -> Sin[ϕ] Sin[θ], z -> Cos[θ]};
$Assumptions = 0 < θ < π && 0 < ϕ < π/2;
```

The expressions

```
x^5/(x^2 + y^2) /. coordinates // FullSimplify
x^5/(1 - z^2) /. coordinates // FullSimplify
(1 - z^2)^(3/2) ((-1 + y^2 + z^2)/(-1 + z^2))^(5/2) /. coordinates // FullSimplify
(y^3 z^5)/((x^2 + y^2)^(3/2) (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(5/2)) /. coordinates // FullSimplify
x^5/((x^2 + y^2) (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)^(3/2)) /. coordinates // FullSimplify
```

all return

```
Cos[ϕ]^5 Sin[θ]^3
```

So does any (properly weighted) linear combination thereof.

Needless to say, only the last option is homogeneous in `x, y, z`, so it is in a sense special.

---

For more general problems (where there is no predefined natural set of coordinates), you can proceed as follows. We assume that the new set of coordinates is three-dimensional, for otherwise the solution is non-unique. If you want to restrict yourself to some two-dimensional submanifold you can always set one of the coordinates to any value of your choice.

Take for example the coordinates $a,b,c$ defined by
$$
x=a\log b,\quad y=c\log b,\quad z=a c \log b
$$
and say you want to obtain the value of the expression
$$
a\ e^b+\frac{c}{ab}
$$

Then you can use the code

```
coordinates = {x == a Log[b], y == c Log[b], z == a c Log[b]};
inverse = Solve[coordinates, {a, b, c}][[1]] // Normal;

a E^b + c/(a b) /. inverse
```

whose output is

```
(E^(-((x y)/z)) y)/x + (E^E^((x y)/z) z)/y
```

As a check,

```
% /. ToRules@*And @@ coordinates // Simplify
(* c/(a b) + a E^b *)
```

Comment: I have several concerns about this answer: 1.- I do not know why you emphasise "not unique" and, 2.- why you restrict the angle $\phi$ if $0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi$?

Comment: @JoséAntonioDíazNavas 1) the emphasis on "non unique" is, well, because the question has no unique answer. OP is asking for *the* expression in terms of `x,y,z`, but there are an infinite number of non-equivalent expressions. Strictly speaking, the question is ill-posed. 2) the restriction in the angles is to help `FullSimplify` do its job. Without it, the third and fourth expressions contain factors of  `Abs[Sin[...]]`. (In particular, the fourth expression is the one you give in your post; without the restriction in the angles your expression is not identical to the one in the OP).

Comment: @Jose, in fact, your solution implicitly uses coordinate bounds, where Accidental chose to use them explicitly; look at the result of `CoordinateChartData["Spherical", "CoordinateRangeAssumptions", {r, θ, ϕ}]`

Comment: It is non-unique because we used a transformation from 2-dimensional space to 3-dimensional space. So we can generate many solutions using a relation satisfied by x, y, z (which is x^2+y^2+z^2 = 1 in this case).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 7):

I am assuming you have a field in Spherical Coordinates given by your function and you want to transform it in Cartesian Coordinates:

```
CoordinateTransform["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}]

(* {r Cos[\[Phi]] Sin[\[Theta]], r Sin[\[Theta]] Sin[\[Phi]], r Cos[\[Theta]]} *)
```

Then, use `TransformedField`:

```
TransformedField["Spherical" -> "Cartesian", Cos[\[Phi]]^5 Sin[\[Theta]]^3, 
                  {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]} -> {x, y, z}]
```

$$\frac{x^5}{\left(x^2+y^2\right) \left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)^{3/2}}$$

See the documentation for further info.

Comment: Thank you. I see that Mathematica has a large basis of standard coordinate systems built in. But I wonder, what should I do, when I want to use some non-standard (local) coordinates, given by some formulae? I don't see any examplex in the documentation, even though the syntax of TransformedField function suggests it should be possible.

Comment: @Janusz, that sounds like it should be a new question.

Comment: @JanuszPrzewocki I updated my answer.